# How to create new columns from existing columns in django sqlite models.py files?

Tags: python, django, web, sqlite

I am creating a simple result processing system using django.
I made this class:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    Course_Code = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True,primary_key = True)
    Course_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Dept = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Credit_Lecture = models.IntegerField()
    Credit_Tutorial = models.IntegerField()
    Credit_Practical = models.IntegerField()
    Max_Marks_MidTerm = models.IntegerField()
    Max_Marks_Theory = models.IntegerField()
    Max_Marks_Pr = models.IntegerField()
```

Now I want to make a new column that stores the total credit value of a course i.e. :

Credit_Total =  Credit_Lecture  + Credit_Tutorial + Credit_Practical

How should I do so?
I found the following possibilities but failed:

```
Total_Credit =Credit_Lec + Credit_Tut + Credit_Pr

Total_credit = SELECT CAST(Credit_lec AS VARCHAR(255)) AS credit_lec FROM Course;
```

Comment: Why do you want to create a column for that? Better to write a method that calculates the value when you need it.

Comment: How should I do so?Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You also could create a Property in the model like

```
@property
def total_credit(self):
    tc = self.Credit_Lecture + self.Credit_Tutorial + self.Credit_Practical
    return tc
```

add it in the Courses class

Wherever you want this info displayed, you rely to it as.

```
tc = Course.total_credit
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where in the file should i add these lines?and also where to call this method so that to all the courses in the database a column of total credit gets added?

Comment: I edited my answer. You place the @property IN the class Course. From outside, it acts like a column kind of. You can also use it in a template like {{ xxx.total_credit }}, where xxx is the Course cursor name you would pass into the template